# PHP Website on Mobile Device

Tags: php, html, css, mobile, responsive

I have a Google App Engine PHP website and all works fine. But obviously when it is loaded on a mobile device it loads just like a normal web page. Whats the best way to 'convert' the web page to look better when it is loaded on a mobile device? via CSS?

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Comment: ^ that and [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for responsive web design, or pages that adapt to the screen size. Some common responsive CSS frameworks are [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).